# populate with condition in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a movie booking data like below

movie order schema

```
 {
    "movie_id": "5d64fb7975214a183bf10f5b",
    "variant_id": "5d64fda8fc7f911a77afd55c",

 }
```

and movie schema data like below

```
{  
   "_id":"5d64fb7975214a183bf10f5b",
   "description":"Sahoo movie ",
   "options":[  

   ],
   "variants":[  
      {  
         "enabled":true,
         "_id":"5d64fda8fc7f911a77afd55c",
         "variant_name":"",
         "regular_price":345,
         "sale_price":125,
         "stock_quantity":45,
      },
      {  
         "enabled":true,
         "_id":"5d661c8181a4572a27f048dd",
         "variant_name":"",
         "regular_price":120,
         "sale_price":50,
         "stock_quantity":10,
      }
   ],

   "on_sale":false,
   "variable":true
}
```

now I'm trying to querying the movie order

```
let data = await MovieOrder.find().populate(movie_id)
```

but it is giving movie details with all the variant.but what I'm looking for here is

> In the `movie order` what is the `variant_id` is present based on that I need to populate the `movie` with variant based on that variant id on the movie order

**Note:**  the result should be, what are the `variant_id` in the movie order schema is equal to variant id in the movie schema

Hope you guys understand my problem, please give me the solution

Answer (score 1):

With the way your schema is designed it is hard for populate to filter the movies variants array with the `variant_id` in the movies order 
as this is not how populate works.

In order to use populate properly, you would have to change the movies schema making the variants array as `ref` to 
`Variants` model. For example, your schema definitions would need to look like

**Schema definitions**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const variantSchema = new Schema({
    enabled: Boolean,
    variant_name: String,
    regular_price: Number,
    sale_price: Number,
    stock_quantity: Number
})

const Variant = mongoose.model('Variant', variantSchema)

const movieSchema = new Schema({
    description:  String,
    options:   [String],
    variants: [{ type: 'ObjectId', ref: 'Variant' }],
    on_sale: Boolean,
    variable: Boolean
})

const Movie = mongoose.model('Movie', movieSchema)


await MovieOrder.find().populate('movie_id variant_id')
```

This way your query just returns the movie and the variant it needs.

---

However, if the current schema design remains as it is, you can use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) in an aggregate pipeline to do the `populate` and then filter the resulting array using [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) on the variant that matches the `variant_id` field in your `MovieOrder` model:

```
await MovieOrder.aggregate([
    { '$lookup': {
        'from': 'movies',
        'localField': "movie_id",    // field in the movieorders collection
        'foreignField': "_id",  // field in the movies collection
        'as': "movie"
    } },
    { '$addFields': { 
        'movie': { '$arrayElemeAt': ['$movie', 0 ] }
    } },
    { '$addFields': { 
        'movie.variants': { 
            '$filter': {
                'input': '$movie.variants',
                'cond': { '$eq': ['$variant_id', '$$this._id'] }
            }
        }
    } },
]).exec()
```